# No connection adapters were found for | Python 3.5 | Requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to extract articles from several URLs gathered in a csv file.
However when I print the output I get this error: 
InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for '['http://www.nytimes.com/2016/10/06/world/europe/police-brussels-knife-terrorism.html']'

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('Training_news.csv', newline='') as file:
    reader= csv.reader (file, delimiter=' ')
    for row in reader:
        r=requests.get(row)
        r.encoding = "ISO-8859-1"
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
        text = soup.find_all(("p",{"class": "story-body-text story-content"}))
```

I think the issue is in "row", when I print it I don't get a single list with all the URLs in the csv file but a list for any single value of the file:
    ['http://www.nytimes.com/2016/10/06/world/europe/police-brussels-knife-terrorism.html']
['http://www.nytimes.com/2016/06/29/world/europe/turkey-istanbul-airport-explosions.html']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`row` is a list.  `requests.get` expects a string.  You could do something like this, iterating over the items in each row:

```
with open('Training_news.csv', newline='') as file:
    reader= csv.reader (file, delimiter=' ')
    for row in reader:
        for url in row:
            r=requests.get(url)
            r.encoding = "ISO-8859-1"
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
            text = soup.find_all(("p",{"class": "story-body-text story-content"}))
```